# How can you check from a 'ls' output in UNIX if each item in results is a directory or a file

Tags: unix

How can you check from a 'ls' output in UNIX if each item in results is a directory or a file

I have thousands of files and folders. All created in error as, example

```
HHYY
KKJH
JGGF
```

The problem is in some case an item should be an actual file and not a foldere.

Example

```
HHYY
KKJH.txt
JGGF
```

So I need to now move all actual files to a new location and I am trying identify files

Comment: Thanks Michael. We are on to something. The problem here is i need the files listed to a log text file as KKJH. Right now they are listed as ./KKJH. I am going to eventualy right a script to do the move since each file is to be stored in a unique folder with its name

Comment: `find . -type f` will recursively list all plain files; `find . -type d` will recursively list all directories.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *
do
  if [ -f "$file" ]
  then ...
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`ls -l` has some below kind of output.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 oct 9 2011 xml
```

in the above line the first character "d" indicates that its a directory.
if the first character is "l",it indicates its a symbolic link.

Hope this helps.